# laravel php artisan migrate does not create a new table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, migration

I have created a user migration and then created the table. Here is the command:

```
php artisan migration:make create_users_table --table=users --create
```

And then I updated the schema for my desired fields, and ran this command:

```
php artisan migration
```

And it works and created the table with all of its field.

Then I again typed the following command to create a new table's schema for comments table"

```
php artisan migration:make create_comments_table --table=comments --create
```

And it worked.

**And I updated the actual schema of the table, but then when I commanded php artisan migrate it throws an error:**

```
Base table or view already exists. table 'users' ....
```

Why? because I'm creating the comments table, what it has to do with users table.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid problems, try creating the tables like these

```
php artisan migrate:make create_users_table --table=users --create=users

php artisan migrate:make create_comments_table --table=comments --create=comments
```

taking note of the arguments in `--create` for each cli command.

Answer (score 1):

> php artisan migrate:make create_comments_table --table=comments
>   --create

The --table and --create options may also be used to indicate the name of the table, and whether the migration will be creating a new table

[migrations](http://laravel.com/docs/migrations)

Comment: Sorry, but I changed the typo that you made before you edit you question again .